# unable to upload image file to S3 bucket via PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to upload an image to my S3 Bucket via AWS PHP SDK. For my EC2 instance, I have attached a role that allows PutObject and GetObject for my S3 Bucket. Therefore, I do not need to attach credentials when creating the S3Client, supposedly. I'm still learning.

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
require './aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;

$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
]);

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

try {
    $result = $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => 'bucket name',
        'Key' => 'testimage1',
        'Body' => $filename
    ]);
    echo 'DONE';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

I keep getting a 500 internal error in this form. Apparently the error occurs at S3Client creation, I'm not sure why.

Further probing confirms, that when I try to instantiate the S3Client class, the 500 internal error is thrown. I am able to access the S3 bucket from the CLI but unable to do so using the AWS PHP SDK.

Here is the image of the error:
[image: error image]

Can anyone advice in this? Thank you for reading.

Comment: And what exactly is the error?

Comment: @pdu, updated the post with error.

Comment: 500 error can be basically anything, try reading server error logs, commenting out parts of code, make request via Postman, etc. to find out what can be wrong

Comment: It seems that instantiating the S3Client causes the 500 internal error. I'm still not sure why, anybody have experience here? I have given the EC2 instance full access to the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it but I used composer. So here's a step by step guide.

This is under the assumption that you have created an IAM role with full S3 access or at least with the PutObject policy attached, and the IAM role is attached to the EC2 instance. Also that your EC2 instance has installed a web server.

1. In the EC2 instance `/var/www/html` (folder where your web server hosts your webpage), install composer as guided through [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-macos) in your project folder. I chose to install composer globally for convenience sake.
2. Install AWS PHP SDK as seen in this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_installation.html).
3. If you an encounter an error asking for simplexml extension, just `yum install php-xml` and rerun the installation of AWS PHP SDK.
4. Now that you have the SDK installed, you can now upload the file you want to the S3 bucket.

Here is my code for uploading, my vendor folder is root level with the php file used for uploading files to the S3 bucket.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

try{
  $sharedConfig = [
      'region' => 'us-east-1',
      'version' => 'latest'
  ];

  $sdk = new Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig); /*Instantiate SDK class with configs for API use*/

  $s3Client = $sdk->createS3(); /*creates the S3 Client for API use*/

  $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name']; /*file name e.g. name.jpg */

  $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; /*!!! IMPORTANT - this is what you need to supply the SourceFile to properly upload the file*/

  $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type']; /*file type*/

  /*print_r($_FILES['file']);*/
  $result = $s3Client->putObject([
    'Bucket' => 'bucket-name',
    'Key' => 'testimage.jpg',
    'SourceFile' => $file_tmp_name,
    'ContentType'=>$file_type,
    'ContentDisposition'=>'attachment'
  ]);
  echo "FILE SENT";
}catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the use of the S3Client Class is like this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_configuration.html

```php
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$options = [
    'region'            => 'us-east-1',
    'version'           => '2006-03-01',
    'signature_version' => 'v4'
];

$s3Client = new S3Client($options);
```

It also says, "We do not recommend Using latest in a production application because pulling in a new minor version of the SDK that includes an API update could break your production application."

Comment: I’ve changed the version but the error persists.

Comment: Have you changed to `$s3Client = new S3Client`

Comment: Yes, I did do so. It could be an error with IAM role assignment. I’ll be back.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be the IAM role, I gave it full access to the S3 bucket. I am able to access the S3 bucket from the command line.

Comment: I'm a dumbass. It was a pathing issue that can be solved easily if I'd just used composer.